# Ion-item with *ngFor in a dropdown

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like to set a button that opens and hides some `ion-item` in a dropdown.

I know that there might be a solution in the docs but I am unable to find it

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Technical Information</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>Manuales</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let m of manuals">
      <ion-label>{{m}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <!-- Other <ion-list-header>s and <ion-item>s -->
</ion-content>
```

I would like to hide and show all Items when clicking on each ion-list-header, show his own `ion-item` with `*ngFor`, like if there are 20 manuals, dropdown all 20 manuals and hide others `ion-list-header`s...

Is there a way to do it with this structure or maybe with another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Technical Information</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let m of manuals; let i=index">
        <ion-list-header>
            <ion-label (click)="showOrHide(i)">Manuales</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>
        <ion-list id="{{i}}" style="display:none">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let m of m.list">
                <ion-label>{{m}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

In `.ts` component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController , AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})


export class HomePage {
  manuals = [{
    id:1,
    list: ["1","2","3"]
  },
  {
    id:2,
    list: ["1","2","3"]
  },
  {
    id:3,
    list: ["1","2","3"]
  },
  {
    id:4,
    list: ["1","2","3"]
  }]

  constructor() {

  }

  showOrHide(id){
    const listItemShow = document.getElementById(id);
    if(listItemShow.style.display === "none")
      listItemShow.style.display = "block"
    else
      listItemShow.style.display = "none"
  }
}
```

Comment: It works for me, does what I requested, but it displays 20 times "Manuales", the `ion-list-header`, but I can edit a little the code so does not repeat 20 times the same, Thanks!!!

Comment: it's up to your data :D i just give you an example for your case. nice to help you